# Would one thinking that they are cool imply that they are?

Tags: history-of-philosophy

If "I think, therefore I am" is correct wouldn't thinking you are "cool" imply that you are because you think therefore your are? And since that is the case, you would have to be "cool", right?

**For Example**

David: John just thinks he's cool.

Comment: "I think therefore I am" only refers to bare existence, because you cannot think without existing. By contrast, if you thought you were a ham sandwich, this would not suffice to prove that you were a ham sandwich.

Comment: @NieldeBeaudrap if you turn this into an answer I'll upvote it.

Comment: Yes, I understand what you are saying with the ham sandwich expample. I was just reffering to if one was to say that they was an adjective for example in this case "cool".

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**On thinking implying being**

"I think therefore I am" only refers to bare existence, because you cannot think without existing. By contrast, if you thought you were a ham sandwich, this would not suffice to prove that you were a ham sandwich.

**On coolness**

After years of observation, I would say that 'coolness' consists of consistently acting in a way which people find calm, unconventional, and in a self-possessed and unconcerned manner. In particular, anyone who is substantially interested in how other people perceive them and spends much of their time thinking about it — for instance, anyone who spends time contemplating whether or not they are 'cool' — are unlikely actually to be cool. In this respect, coolness is much like the Buddhist concept of Englightenment: it involves a lack of emotional fixation, including the pursuit of Enlightenment/coolness itself.

(There is a notion of 'coolness' which is actually conformist, *e.g.* the things which "all the cool kids" do. I would class this as a sort of error of the same type as cargo cult science, except in the domain of personal self-determination and corollaries to personality extending from it.)

Comment: Does this mean that Justin Bieber isn't cool?

Comment: @thisfeller: I wouldn't know. He's unlikely to be cool in his social interaction with his fans -- exciting, maybe. How he interacts with people in a context other than his profession might be different.

Comment: @nieldebeaudrap Thank you! I was just wondering!